# Cancel auto triggering value changed event for UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, uikit, uiswitch

Is it possible to cancel auto triggering value changed event for UISwitch?
I have action of touch up inside event for the UISwitch, I wanna do background job first and then when job is done, i manually turn the switch on instead of it turns itself on immediately after touch even the background job isn't done yet.

Comment: I think that users will be confused by this UI. If the user sees no change in the switch when they slide it, they will think something is wrong. If you want this behavior, you should probably design a control that doesn't look like Apple's UISwitch.

Comment: I have the indicator next to it to indicate background work going

Comment: You should disable it until your background job completes. This will show your user that the switch is currently not available. The indicator will give a hint to the user, that work is in progress and the switch will soon be available.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just not add a target action for the `.ValueChanged` event. Just do the switching in you're background task completion handler.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
    println("This is run on the background queue")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        aSwitch.value = true
    })
})
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I just understood your question. You meant that the value of the switch should not change first when the user presses it, right?

**Answer:**

You can set `userInteractionEnabled = false` for the switch, then add a UIView on top of it (not a subview of the witch) with a tapGestureRecognizer. Then handle the background events when tapped, and turn on/off the switch.

Comment: how to not add valuechanged event? does touch up inside event auto trigger valuechanged event?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of the "continues" feature, so you will only get a Value Changed event after touch up inside. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: so it only change the value but not the UI in this way?

Comment: see the `continous` property in the docs: "Contains a Boolean value indicating whether changes in the sliders value generate continuous update events." That's the behavior you described with touch up inside. You can also disable it, that will change the Style of the slider, to show that it is currently disabled. It's not a good idea to disable a slider while not showing this to the user. User might get confused and think your app is not responding.

Comment: The OP is using a UISwitch, not a slider.

Comment: oh sry, never mind. You should really not disable a switch without indication to the user. You could anyways just check the value of the slider when you background job completes.